# How to edit a webpack imported variable?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm a tad new to building javascript with webpack and I'm having a problem understanding how to edit imported variables.

module1.js

```
export var number_variable = 1
```

module2.js

```
import {number_variable} from "./module1.js"
console.log(number_variable) // correctly logs variable
number_variable = number_variable + 1 // throws error
```

Throws:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: number_variable is not defined
```

What am I missing about how to work with webpack imported variables?

Comment: use typescript for ease

Comment: Thanks @harkal - can you summarise why I would find TS easier?

Comment: i find ts easy because it provides type checks and linting which makes things easier. moreover the visual studio code have very nice intellisense which improves productivity. your code ll be more organised with classes and objects. js is more of raw language while ts is organised and structured

Comment: and this is error is because of scope of the variable[i think] you can create another variable in the file and copy the value to it and then it should work

Comment: Sounds good @harkal. I'd heard of it, but not known if/when I should use it. Is it compatible with the webpack/node that I've just learnt about?

Comment: you ll fall in love with it once you start using it. it is compatiable with every new thing in the market and the community arround it amazing

Comment: @harkal with regard to scope, in this case, a copy would do, but I'm confused if it were the case that I needed this variable to be shared between modules. I generally confused about this at the moment though, so it might clear up as I learn more.

Comment: @harkal thanks, will give it a go!

Comment: for using the variable from other class you should be including the whole file then i think it ll work.

Comment: @harkal is another class equivalent to another module here? Also, from what you say, variable imports are 'one way' things? They never change an instance of a variable available between two modules?

Comment: the concept of modues exists basically for code organisation. it has nothing to do with classes. and yes when i say copy the variable i mean the value wont be propogated to the oher file unless you imprort the whole file

Comment: Thanks again @harkal, your suggestion worked and I understood your explanation. I'm assuming what you say about classes translates onto non-object oriented code.

Comment: classes follow OOP concept while the modules are just for managing code

Comment: @harkal ah I why I was confused about that now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "edit" something that is exported from another module. That is one of the features of ES Modules.

The issue here, though, is two-fold:

1. `import` identifiers are not variables, they are *bindings*. You cannot reassign or redefine them. From [MDN's article on the `import` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) (emphasis my own):

   > The static import statement is used to import **read only** live bindings which are exported by another module.
2. Webpack performs optimisations to source code in order to reduce the size of output bundles. In this instance, it has identified that `number_variable` will never change (remember from above, the rules of ES Modules prohibit it from changing) and holds a scalar value (an integer).

   This means it can safely lift out the scalar value and inline it. After that, `module1.js` *only* contains a now unused export declaration for `number_variable`, so it can safely discard the `module1.js` module altogether. This is called dead-code elimination, or [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/).

To demonstrate (2) you can see below what `module2.js` looks like as a function module inside the compiled Webpack bundle (produced by running `webpack --entry module2.js`):

```
function(e, t, r) {
    "use strict";
    r.r(t);
    console.log(1), number_variable = 2
}
```

Notice that Webpack has inlined the value of `number_variable` as the argument to `console.log` and also pre-calculated the addition calculation and inlined the result of that. Because of this, no identifier `number_variable` exists in scope of the `number_variable = 2` assignment.

Another thing is that the function has [strict-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) enabled, by the `"use strict";` statement at the top of the function. This makes it illegal to create global variables by accident by doing something exactly like `number_variable = 2`, instead throwing a ReferenceError.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.

Comment: You can also set fields of an object that's been exported.  The object var name can't be reassigned, but the object it points to can be changed.

module1.js

export var holder = {number_variable = 1};

module2.js

import {holder} from "./module1.js"
console.log(holder.number_variable) // correctly logs variable
holder.number_variable = holder.number_variable + 1 // throws error

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason behind the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" is executing the jQuery code before the jQuery library file has loaded. Therefore make sure that you're executing the jQuery code only after jQuery library file has finished loading.

Example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery - $ is not defined</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        alert("jQuery is working perfectly.");
    });      
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button">Test jQuery Code</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't think this could be related to JQuery though. I'll update my question to show that the variable is available prior to a certain line.

Comment: Sure that would be helpful to answer!

Comment: pls see note on module 2